# ASP.net: Dynamic BoundFields

Tags: c#, asp.net

In a GridView, I'm trying to show either one column or an other using a public Boolean property:

```
   <Columns>
   ...

    <asp:BoundField Visible="<%= !ShowPurchaseDate %>" DataField="Published" HeaderText="Publicerad" SortExpression="PriceRange" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy.MM.dd}" HtmlEncode="false" />

    <asp:BoundField Visible="<%= ShowPurchaseDate %>" DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Köpt" SortExpression="OrderDate" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy.MM.dd}" HtmlEncode="false" />

   ...
  </Columns>
```

But I'm getting an error message saying that it's not possible to create a System.Boolean from a string that contains <% !ShowPurchaseDate %> for property Visisble.

How can I achive this?

UPDATE:

<%# !ShowPurchaseDate %> doesn't work either as there's no databinding going on.

Using a protected funktion doesn't work either (same error message as with property).

Comment: Did you return a string from the method?

Comment: Since it is a BoundField, there's data-binding. You have to make it a template field to work.

Comment: Albert is right about data binding. However, the BoundField itself is not data-bound. If it was, you'd need <%#. Convert it to a template if you want to use it (the <%= is render directive which shouldn't be used in this context). Or set visibility in code behind (as you did).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it through:

```
gridMain.Columns[ShowPurchaseDate ? 3 : 4].Visible = false;
```

Is this the best solution?

Comment: That's not the best solution. It is based on indexes that change all the time. Make it a template field and use the data-binding approach I suggested.

Comment: With a template field, you can make the controls in the column disappear but not the whole column. So, I agree that it needs to be done in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a protected method in the code behind that returns the boolean property as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You're code should be **<%# !ShowPurchaseDate %>**

Comment: Who gave -1? The answer is correct... DataBound field does require usage of <%# %> and not <%= %>

Comment: I forgot to add, that the BoundField itself is not a data-bound control, so template would be required.

Answer (score 0):

you could try calling a method instead of binding like shouldshowcolumn().